# Node.js - Not able to get redirect Uri

Tags: node.js, request

so I am making a GET request to Angellist with my clientID, and then they will redirect me to a url with a "code" appended to the url and I need to extract that code in order to send a POST request to them to attain the auth_token. I am doing this on a Node.js script and I am wondering how I'm able to extract the redirect url after sending the initial GET request? Here is the FAQ to the angellist API: https://angel.co/api/oauth/faq. Any help is appreciated, thanks all!

```
var request = require("request");

var url = https://angel.co/api/oauth/authorize?
client_id=*************&
state=email&
response_type=code

var r = request({
        uri: url,
        method: "GET",
        followRedirect: true
    },
    function (err, res, body) {
        console.log(res.uri); //I want the REDIRECT URL
    })
```